# Should I use "using" on my SitkaSoapServiceClient?

Tags: cloud, ssds, sql-data-services, sql-server-data-services

(This relates to Microsoft's SitkaSoapService, in the service reference at https://database.windows.net/soap/v1/)

I'm using SitkaSoapServiceClient to access my SQL Data Services database by SOAP.

Should I use a "using" statement every time I use this proxy class? Or does it do its own connection handling in a safe way internally?

I.e. do I need to say:

```
using (SitkaSoapServiceClient proxy = GetProxy())
    proxy.Update(scope, entity);
```

... or is it safe to say:

```
GetProxy().Update(scope, entity);
```

[where GetProxy() returns a SitkaSoapServiceClient object.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the proxy class code compile when wrapped in a using statement? If so, it implements `IDisposable` and I'd use it.

EDIT: calling Dispose() should incur little overhead if it does nothing, and if the designer of the class decides at a later date to allocate unmanaged resources you will be protected from a leak.

Comment: It does implement IDisposable, but I remember there being a similar debate around LinqToSql's DataContext - this implements it too, but the Microsoft brains behind it swore that the "using" was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `using` when the class implements IDisposable, because the author of the class tells you that it contains some resources that should be freed.